# Can't connect LG5 to Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, lg

I have an LG5 and I am trying to connect it to android studio. However, Android Studio is not showing my phone under the devices.

What I already did:

1. Downloaded the drivers on my laptop
2. Pressed the "Build number" button 7 times
3. Enabled USB debugging on my phone
4. Connected my phone to my laptop via USB

What could be the issue:
I have a prepaid monthly AT&T phone plan and I elected to not pay an extra $10 to make my phone a mobile hotspot. When I try to switch on "USB tethering," I get an error message on my phone saying that it was unsuccessful and I need to contact AT&T.

I have a suspicion that I need to pay the extra $10 per month (which wouldn't be an issue if that allows me to use my phone as a developer) in order to turn on USB tethering before my phone works. However, I just wanted to check here before I potentially pay $120/yr needlessly.

Do I need to enable USB tethering on my phone in order for Android Studio to recognize it? Is there something else I could try first?

Comment: All you need to do to connect your phone to your PC for development is enable USB debugging in your phones developer options. USB tethering is for sharing internet connection with other devices and is unrelated, so don't pay for anything. If you're having trouble read this guide about ADB debugging: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb and also read this about how to connect to your PC and Android Studio wirelessly: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless

Comment: Thank you for your help! I successfully enabled USB debugging. My laptop's file explorer recognizes my phone when I plug it in via a USB cord. I can move files between the folders on my phone and laptop. Unfortunately, Android Studio still does not recognize my phone.

Comment: If you click Run, did you see the window "Select Deployment Target" showing your device ?

Comment: No, I did not see that window.

To clarify, when you say, "click Run," do you mean pressing the "play" button or clicking "Run" on the top menu? No window entitled "Select Deployment Target" opened when I clicked play, and there was no option entitled"Select Deployment Target" when I clicked "Run" on the options menu.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related. But when I click on the "Play" button to activate the Nexus virtual device, I see an error code saying, "Unable to locate adb." However, the virtual device still starts up.

Comment: Add `adb` on `PATH` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connected via USB there should be a notification on your phone titled "File transfer" Select that and then change the option from "File transfer" to "Photo transfer"

Comment: For someone reading this who is as clueless as I am, the notification on the phone said, "Use USB connection for" and had 4 options. The first was, "Charging." The second was, "Media sync (MTP)." The third was, "Send images (PTP)." And the fourth was, "MIDI device." I had previously selected "Media sync." I changed it to "Send images," and that made my phone pop up on the Flutter app (but as something that began with "LM," rather than LG).

Comment: For someone reading this who once selected "Charging", "Power supply", "File Transfer", or "MIDI Device" and then "Always" on his Android phone, your phone will not show the notification when you connect it to a computer using USB. However, you can find the option to change to "Photo Sync" within Developer Options on your phone. On your phone, open Settings, then press "System" and then "Developer Options". Within Developer Options, look in the Networking category, and press "Select USB Configuration".